# Accelerate the distance function of two point sets

Tags: compile, distance

I have two point sets `point` and `impPoint`. I want to calculate a distance function from each element in the `point` set to all elements in `impoint` sets. I have written a compiled version of the function, but its speed is a little slow. Is there any way to speed up the code?

```
w=0.1;
qs=0.1;
n=200;
nn=n*n;
nimp=0.1;
Nimp=IntegerPart[nimp*nn];
point=RandomReal[1,{nn,2}];
impPoint=RandomSample[point,Nimp];
pm=ReplacePart[Table[1,Nimp],(RandomSample[Range[1,Nimp,1],Nimp/2]//Partition[#,1]&)->-1];
cf=Compile[{{w,_Real},{qs,_Real},{pm,_Real,1},{Nimp,_Real},{impPoint,_Real,2},{point,_Real,1}},Total[Table[w/qs^2*Exp[-(((point[[1]]-impPoint[[i,1]])^2+(point[[2]]-impPoint[[i,2]])^2))/qs^2],{i,1,Nimp}]*pm],CompilationTarget->"C",Parallelization->True,RuntimeAttributes->{Listable},RuntimeOptions->"Speed"];
AbsoluteTiming[cf[w,qs,pm,Nimp,impPoint,point]//Total]
```

In fact, `n` takes 5000, so I don't recommend using `DistanceMatrix`, because it saves time but costs a lot of memory.

Comment: @sidy Your function use only first point from the list `point`. Is it your special decision or it is bug?

Comment: @Rom28 The functions actuallly uses all points from the list `point`; it does so by being `Listable`.

Comment: As you perform summation over the Gaussian, the method of choice would probably a fast multipole method (FMM). Unfortunately, FMM is not yet available in _Mathematica_.